# laravel loop through eager loaded nested relationships

Tags: php, foreach, nested-loops, laravel

struggling once again and could do with some help.
It may look looooong but it's not, :)

I have a set of arrays which are eager loaded and relational. here's the code (Laravel)

```
$user = User::with(array('profile','classrooms','warnings','observation','complaint','pmainduction','workshops','grievances','grievances.grievanceaction'))
    ->where('id', '=', $id)->get();
```

This gets the data perfectly for each member of staff when in their profile page. When i loop through grievances and the grievanceaction for each grievance it duplicates the data and doesn't display it like in the print_r

Part of the array is

```
[grievances] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Grievance Object
                            (
                                [attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1
                                        [user_id] => 8
                                        [company] => Company name
                                        [date] => 2012-12-24
                                        [nature] => Visa
                                        [details] => can't renew visa.                                                                                         [action] => emailed company
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    )

                                [original] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1
                                        [user_id] => 8
                                        [company] => Company name
                                        [date] => 2012-12-24
                                        [nature] => Visa
                                        [details] => can't renew visa.                                                                                  [action] => emailed company
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [created_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                        [updated_at] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                                    )

                                [relationships] => Array
                                    (
                                        [grievanceaction] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Grievanceaction Object
                                                    (
                                                        [attributes] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 1
                                                                [action] => do something here                                                                                                                                [grievance_id] => 1
                                                                [created_at] => 2012-12-25 00:00:00
                                                                [updated_at] => 2012-12-25 20:03:04
                                                            )

                                                        [original] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 1
                                                                [action] => do something here
                                                                [grievance_id] => 1
                                                                [created_at] => 2012-12-25 00:00:00
                                                                [updated_at] => 2012-12-25 20:03:04
                                                            )

                                                        [relationships] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                        [exists] => 1
                                                        [includes] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                                [1] => Grievanceaction Object
                                                    (
                                                        [attributes] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 2
                                                                [action] => some text here
                                                                [grievance_id] => 1
                                                                [created_at] => 2012-12-25 00:00:00
                                                                [updated_at] => 2012-12-25 00:00:00
                                                            )

                                                        [original] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 2
                                                                [action] => some text here
                                                                [grievance_id] => 1
                                                                [created_at] => 2012-12-25 00:00:00
                                                                [updated_at] => 2012-12-25 00:00:00
                                                            )

                                                        [relationships] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                        [exists] => 1
                                                        [includes] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                                [exists] => 1
                                [includes] => Array
                                    (
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Grievance Object
                            (
                                [attributes] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 5
                                        [user_id] => 8
                                        [company] => Company name
                                        [date] => 2012-12-25
                                        [nature] => Housing
                                        [details] => another issue here
                                        [action] => meet with company staff
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [created_at] => 2012-12-25 20:24:57
                                        [updated_at] => 2012-12-25 20:24:57
                                    )

                                [original] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 5
                                        [user_id] => 8
                                        [company] => Company name
                                        [date] => 2012-12-25
                                        [nature] => Housing
                                        [details] => another issue here
                                        [action] => meet with company staff
                                        [status] => 1
                                        [created_at] => 2012-12-25 20:24:57
                                        [updated_at] => 2012-12-25 20:24:57
                                    )

                                [relationships] => Array
                                    (
                                        [grievanceaction] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => Grievanceaction Object
                                                    (
                                                        [attributes] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 3
                                                                [action] => different text here
                                                                [grievance_id] => 5
                                                                [created_at] => 2012-12-25 00:00:00
                                                                [updated_at] => 2012-12-25 23:29:21
                                                            )

                                                        [original] => Array
                                                            (
                                                                [id] => 3
                                                                [action] => different text here
                                                                [grievance_id] => 5
                                                                [created_at] => 2012-12-25 00:00:00
                                                                [updated_at] => 2012-12-25 23:29:21
                                                            )

                                                        [relationships] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                        [exists] => 1
                                                        [includes] => Array
                                                            (
                                                            )

                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )
```

As you can see i have grievance objects 1 & 2 and each of them has its own grievanceaction.
In my output i would like to achieve this

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  Grievance name: 1  |   Date:     |   Action:    |  Status: |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   (grievanceaction data for 1st grievance in loop )        |
|   action: relationship action here      date: with date    |
|                                                            |
--------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  Grievance name: 2  |   Date:     |   Action:    |  Status: |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   (grievanceaction data for 2nd grievance in loop )        |
|   action: relationship action here      date: with date    |
|                                                            |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I currently have

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  Grievance name: 1  |   Date:     |   Action:    |  Status: |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   (grievanceaction data for 1st grievance in loop )         |
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
--------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------
|  Grievance name: 2  |   Date:     |   Action:    |  Status: |
--------------------------------------------------------------
|   (grievanceaction data for 1st grievance in loop )         |
|                                                             |
|                                                             |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

code is

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered">

@if(empty($user['0']->grievances))
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <th colspan="3">  No Grievances logged.</th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
@else
   <thead>

@foreach ($user['0']->grievances as $grievance )

<tr>
<th>Date: {{ date("d-M-Y",strtotime($grievance->date)) }}</th>
<th>Nature: {{ $grievance->nature }}</th>
<th>Initial Action:</strong> {{ $grievance->action }}  </th>
<th>Status: 

    @if ( $grievance->status == 1 )
          Active
    @else
          Resolved
    @endif
</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">Description: {{ $grievance->details }} </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="4">

              <!-- here is where i try and loop through the grievanceactions -->

              <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <tr>
              <th scope="col">Date</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
              </tr>
              <tbody>
              @foreach ($user['0']->grievances['0']->grievanceaction as $grievance )
              <tr>
              <td>{{ date("D, d-M-Y H:i",strtotime($grievance->created_at)) }}</td>
              <td>{{ $grievance->action }}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
              </tbody>
              </table>
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach

@endif
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I would really appreciate some help, thanks

:)

Comment: I hope your code is in pseudo-code ?

Comment: why? this is according to the documentation. it's laravel templating engine format. the only code which should be wrong is maybe my loop ( $user['0']->grievances['0']->grievanceaction as $grievance ). please explain your comment?? [link](http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent) and [link](http://laravel.com/docs/views/templating#blade-control-structures)

Comment: Because it's not native PHP. There is nowhere in your question that it is `laravel`. After your comment I did a search for it and the only place where I should find that information is in the title and tags. So please update your question and make clear it is about laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you hardcoded that you always take the grievanceactions from the `$user['0']->grievances['0']` eg the first one. The grievanceaction loop should be:

```php
              @foreach ($grievance->grievanceaction as $grievanceaction )
              <tr>
              <td>{{ date("D, d-M-Y H:i",strtotime($grievanceaction->created_at)) }}</td>
              <td>{{ $grievanceaction->action }}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
```

Edit: A few notes:

1. There is a `@forelse` loop in Blade which has an `@empty` part, this saves an if at the top.
2. You don't need to use `get()` for the user, you can simply use `first()` so ['0'] not needed every time.
3. It is a common practice to name *-many relations plural to indicate it is an array of results (grievanceaction -> grievanceactions).

Comment: Thanks very much, worked perfectly and the explanation and tips were very helpful. I made the changes and got everything working except i changed the ->get() to ->first but if i remove the ['0'] i get errors. where can i now delete the ['0'] from? Thanks

Comment: `first()` should return a single model (User here), not an array of models, thus you don't need to loop the users and/or use the array accessor.

Comment: Thanks, i finally got it working and understand what's happening now. Much appreciated. you wouldn't know about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040495/laravel-insert-loop-with-many-to-many-relationship) by any chance? :)